# discord.js v13 check if member is in a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to check if a member is or not in a server. 
This is my current code:

```js
function CheckIfManagerIsInServer(client, server_id, member) {
    let isIn = { isIn: true, isNotIn: [] };

    if (CheckIfIsInChain(server_id)) {
        database.chains.forEach(chain => {
            if(chain.membersID.includes(server_id)) {
                chain.members.forEach(server => {

                    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(server)

                    // check if member is in the server

                })
            }
        })
    }

    return isIn;
}
```

`member` parameter is the id of the member. 
How i can check if the member is or not in the server (`guild`)?
I'm using v13.5.0. 
My bot is verified and it has `GUILD_MEMBERS` enabled. 
I have tried multiple methods but they doesn't works. 
How I can do? 
Thank you in advance and sorry for bad english!

Comment: `guild.members.cache.has("ID")`

Comment: @Jakye already tried, returns `undefined`.

Comment: @BlackdestinyXX that returns true or false... what returns undefined?

Comment: @MrMythical nothing, I've fixed the problem.

Comment: And what was it?

Answer (score 0):

For checking that you can do like this

```js
if (guild.members.cache.find(m => m.id === member)?.id) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```